# Context does not contain a definition for ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to execute a query against my data model with `context.ExecuteStoreCommand` but I keep getting the error message:

```
<object context> does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoreCommand' ...
```

I've used this before in an old project and I can't see what I'm missing. I've got project references to EntityFramework, System.Data, System.Data.Entity. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) says that ObjectContext is part of System.Data.Object but I can't reference that directly and I've not needed to reference it where I've used it before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The code where I'd originally used ExecuteStoreCommand had been on an EF4 project where the Code Generation Strategy was set to "Default" which leads to an ObjectContext being created. Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654180/543538) it seems that EF5 on VS2012 creates a DbContext for the data model by default.

I found two ways around this problem.

1 - Change from DbContext to ObjectContext by changing the code generation strategy. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082546/is-there-an-objectcontext-generator-for-entity-framework-5-0) shows how to do it. `<object context>.ExecuteStoreCommand()` can then be used.

2 - Execute the SQL command against the DbContext, for example:

`<db context>.Database.SqlQuery(typeof(myTable), "SELECT * FROM myTable")`

Comment: Here's how to get ObjectContext from DbContext http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059900/convert-dbcontext-to-objectcontext-for-use-with-gridview

Comment: @qujck - I came across that when I was looking for an answer but  forgot to include it, thanks.